# Could not load required libraries. Please check your installation and make sure you activated any necessary virtual environment

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am working on a simple Python project using Poetry using a template, with some dependencies and files.

I have installed the dependencies with: `poetry install`

And then when I run: `poetry run python src/server/app/__main__.py`

I get the following:

> Could not load required libraries.   Please check your installation
> and make sure you activated any necessary virtual environment

I am not really quite sure what's the issue since from a quick Google search there is no mention of anyone that has experienced this error.

Here is the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
classifiers = [
  "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
  "Environment :: Web Environment",
  "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
  "Natural Language :: English",
  "Operating System :: OS Independent",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
  "Programming Language :: Python",
  "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
  "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries",
  "Topic :: Software Development",
  "Typing :: Typed",
]
description = "Opinionated template for integrating Starlite with a SPA"
documentation = "https://cofin.github.io/starlite-full-stack-example"
homepage = "https://github.com/cofin/starlite-full-stack-example"
include = ["CHANGELOG.md"]
keywords = ["api", "rest", "http", "asgi", "pydantic", "starlette", "fastapi", "framework", "websocket", "vite", "spa"]
license = "MIT"
maintainers = ["Cody Fincher <cody.fincher@gmail.com>"]
name = "app"
packages = [
  {include = "app", from = "src/server"},
]
readme = "README.md"
repository = "https://github.com/cofin/starlite-full-stack-example"
version = "0.1.0"
[tool.poetry.scripts]
app = "app.__main__:main"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
alembic = "*"
asyncpg = "*"
click = "*"
greenlet = "*"
hiredis = "*"
httpx = "*"
passlib = {version = "*", extras = ["argon2"]}
pydantic = {extras = ["dotenv", "email"], version = "*"}
python = ">=3.10,<4.0"
redis = "*"
rich = "*"
sqlalchemy = {git = "https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy.git", branch = "main", extras = ["asyncio"]}
starlite = {version = "^1.25.0", extras = ["brotli","picologging","structlog"]}
starlite-jwt = "^1.4.0"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "*"}
orjson = "^3.8.3"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
bump2version = "*"
coverage = {extras = ["toml"], version = "*"}
cython = "*"
hypothesis = {extras = ["cli"], version = "*"}
ipykernel = "*"
ipython = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-asyncio = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
pytest-dotenv = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"
tox = "*"

[tool.poetry.group.docs]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.docs.dependencies]
mkdocs = "*"
mkdocs-material = "*"
mkdocstrings = "*"
mkdocstrings-python = "*"

[tool.poetry.group.lint]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.lint.dependencies]
autoflake = "*"
bandit = "*"
black = "*"
blacken-docs = "*"
flake8 = "*"
flake8-bugbear = "*"
flake8-comprehensions = "*"
flake8-mutable = "*"
flake8-print = "*"
flake8-simplify = "*"
flake8-type-checking = "*"
freezegun = "*"
httpx = "*"
isort = "*"
mypy = "*"
pre-commit = "*"
pylint = "*"
pyupgrade = "*"
slotscheck = "*"
types-click = "*"
types-freezegun = "*"
types-passlib = "*"
types-python-jose = "*"
types-pyyaml = "*"
types-redis = "*"

[build-system]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
requires = ["poetry-core", "setuptools", "wheel", "cython"]

[tool.black]
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | venv
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''
include = '\.pyi?$'
line-length = 120
[tool.autoflake]
check = true

[tool.isort]
line_length = 119
multi_line_output = 3
profile = "black"
skip_gitignore = true
src_paths = ["src/server", "test/server"]

[tool.coverage.run]
omit = ["*/tests/server/*"]

[tool.coverage.report]
exclude_lines = [
  'pragma: no cover',
  'if TYPE_CHECKING:',
  'except ImportError as e:',
  '\.\.\.',
  "if __name__ == '__main__':",
]

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--cov=src -v --doctest-modules --doctest-glob=*.md --ignore=migrations"
asyncio_mode = "auto"
env_files = [".env.example"]

[tool.bandit]
exclude_dirs = ["tests"]
skips = ["B101", "B601"]
tests = ["B201", "B301", "B101"]
```

What could cause this? What can I try to find out what's causing this error?

Comment: Show us the `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: Added the  `pyproject.toml`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. By using this Python module you can easily create templates of Python projects. Not only the file system layout of the project files but also the debugger configs for vscode. I also suffered myself the pain of trying to get Python modules without reference errors

Project description
PyArchetype
This project is used to simplify the skeleton creation of python projects
Installation

pip install pyarchetype

Source Code
https://github.com/redcorjo/pyarchetype.git
Version: 2023010702

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command preferably: `poetry run python -m app`.